# DBUnit FlatXMLDataSet insert extremely slow for MySQL containerized database

Tags: java, mysql, database, mariadb, dbunit

I have a FlatXMLDataSet consisting of approx 263k lines that I am trying to load into a MySQL database. I have a much smaller dataset (5k rows) which loads in with no issues. The large dataset isn't overly complex (Names, addresses, emails, etc).

**What I have tried:**

Disabling foreign key checks

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Setting the batch size

```
dbUnitConnection.getConfig().setProperty(org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_BATCHED_STATEMENTS, true);
dbUnitConnection.getConfig().setProperty(org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_BATCH_SIZE, 20000);
```

Why is inserting data into MySQL/MariaDB so slow using DBUnit and is there any way to speed it up? Any help/pointers would be much appreciated as I need this to work.

N.B. The same dataset inserts into Oracle, Postgres, SQLServer etc without issue.

Comment: Did you set autocommit to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to Georg for his comment which sped things up a lot.

The solution was to set autocommit to false for MySQL and then commit the changes manually once the data has been loaded

```
jdbcConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
jdbcConnection.commit();
```

This speeds it up a bit. To make it faster I also had to disable foreign key checks (I did this using the JDBC database url variables)

```
"url:port/schema?useSSL=false&amp;sessionVariables=FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0"
```

Comment: Beside disabling foreign key checks  you should also disable unique key checks: `SET unique_checks=0`.